# Efficient H2 snaphots for integration tests

Tags: java, testing, h2, snapshot

We use H2 in some integration tests and run multiple test steps with a specific state of the database.

We use [`SCRIPT`](http://www.h2database.com/html/grammar.html#script) to dump ("cache") the database state:

```sql
SCRIPT TO '/path/to/dump.sql' CHARSET 'UTF-8'
```

and restore the dump with [`RUNSCRIPT`](http://www.h2database.com/html/grammar.html#runscript) before each test step:

```sql
RUNSCRIPT FROM '/path/to/dump.sql' CHARSET 'UTF-8'
```

If the test steps are short, restoring the database snapshot can dominate the total test execution time.

Since there is no requirement to restore the snapshot with different versions of H2, I’m wondering if there is a more efficient way to snapshot/restore the database?

Maybe by accessing the underlying [MVStore](https://www.h2database.com/html/mvstore.html)?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the nature of your tests and your data you may need to somehow logically separate data for your tests. Fir example test one test uses data for January 1st, a other test uses data for January 2nd. In this case you will populate your database with test data once and do not need to refresh it between tests.